# Theming Simplenews page

Tags: 7, theming, emails

When creating a newsletter, I have the view mode set to Teaser, but the content printed on the newsletter page doesn't follow the template I have for it, it only prints the fields as specified in the content's type display manager.

Is there any way of having it print the content following the template?